# Populate matrix by colname identity

Tags: r, matrix, matching

I have many samples, each one of which has a corresponding abundance matrix. From these abundance matrices, I would like to create a large matrix that contains abundance information for each sample in rows.

For example, a single abundance matrix would look like:

```
           A  B  C  D 
sample1    1  3  4  2
```

where A, B, C, and D represent colnames, and the abundances are the row values.

I would like to populate my larger matrix, which has as colnames all possible letters (A:Z) and all possible samples (sample1:sampleN) as rows, by matching the colname values.

For ex. :

```
         A  B  C  D  E  F  G ....  Z
sample1  1  3  4  2  NA NA NA ....
sample2  NA NA 2  5  7  NA NA ....
sample3  4  NA 6  9  2  NA 2 .....
....
sampleN
```

Different samples have a varying mix of abundances, in no guaranteed order.

When iteratively adding to this larger matrix, how could I ensure that the correct columns are populated by the right abundance values (ex. column "A" is only filled by values corresponding to abundances of "A" in different samples)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting data, changing just a little to highlight differences:

```r
m1 <- as.matrix(read.table(header=TRUE, text="
           A  B  C  Z
sample1    1  3  4  2"))
m2 <- as.matrix(read.table(header=TRUE, text="
         A  B  C  D  E  F  G
sample2  NA NA 2  5  7  NA NA
sample3  4  NA 6  9  2  NA 2"))
```

First, we need to make sure both matrices have the same column names:

```r
newcols <- setdiff(colnames(m2), colnames(m1))
m1 <- cbind(m1, matrix(NA, nr=nrow(m1), nc=length(newcols), dimnames=list(NULL, newcols)))
newcols <- setdiff(colnames(m1), colnames(m2))
m2 <- cbind(m2, matrix(NA, nr=nrow(m2), nc=length(newcols), dimnames=list(NULL, newcols)))

m1
#         A B C Z  D  E  F  G
# sample1 1 3 4 2 NA NA NA NA
m2
#          A  B C D E  F  G  Z
# sample2 NA NA 2 5 7 NA NA NA
# sample3  4 NA 6 9 2 NA  2 NA
```

And now we combine them; regular `cbind` needs the column names to be aligned as well:

```r
rbind(m2, m1[,colnames(m2),drop=FALSE])
#          A  B C  D  E  F  G  Z
# sample2 NA NA 2  5  7 NA NA NA
# sample3  4 NA 6  9  2 NA  2 NA
# sample1  1  3 4 NA NA NA NA  2
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to take advantage of matrix indexing, like so:

```
big[cbind(rownames(abun),colnames(abun))] <- abun
```

Using this example `abun`dance matrix, and a `big` matrix to fill:

```
abun <- matrix(c(1,3,4,2),nrow=1,dimnames=list("sample1",LETTERS[1:4]))
big <- matrix(NA,nrow=5,ncol=26,dimnames=list(paste0("sample",1:5),LETTERS))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `reduce` from `purrr` package and `union_all` from `dplyr` package:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

sample_names <- c("sample1","sample2","sample3")
```

Generating 3 random abundance dataframes:

```
num1 <- round(runif(runif(1,min = 1, max = 10),min = 1, max = 10))
df1 <- data.frame(t(num1))
colnames(df1) <- sample(LETTERS,length(num1))

num2 <- round(runif(runif(1,min = 1, max = 10),min = 1, max = 10))
df2 <- data.frame(t(num2))
colnames(df2) <- sample(LETTERS,length(num2))

num3 <- round(runif(runif(1,min = 1, max = 10),min = 1, max = 10))
df3 <- data.frame(t(num3))
colnames(df3) <- sample(LETTERS,length(num3))
```

This is actually the code that does all the magic:

```
A <- reduce(list(df1,df2,df3),union_all)
col_order <- sort(colnames(A),decreasing = FALSE)
A <- A[,col_order]
rownames(A) <- sample_names
```

Output:

```
> A
         A  C  E  F  O  P  Q  U  W  Y
sample1  9 NA NA NA  9 NA  5  6 NA NA
sample2 NA NA NA NA  5  4 NA NA  5 NA
sample3 NA  6  5  9 NA NA  3 NA  5  7
```